# cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable error

Tags: rust

How can I make the following code compile, what am I doing wrong?

```
fn try_attack(game_state: &mut GameState) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let length = game_state.kingdoms.len();

    let player = game_state.kingdoms.first_mut().unwrap();

    let target = game_state
        .kingdoms
        .get(rng.gen_range(1..length) as usize)
        .unwrap();

    if target.soldiers < player.soldiers || target.gold < player.gold {
        player.gold += (target.gold as f64 * 0.1) as u32;
        player.soldiers += (target.soldiers as f64 * 0.05) as u32;
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `game_state.kingdoms` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src\game_utils.rs:85:18
   |
83 |       let player = game_state.kingdoms.first_mut().unwrap();
   |                    ------------------------------- mutable borrow occurs here
84 |
85 |       let target = game_state
   |  __________________^
86 | |         .kingdoms
87 | |         .get(rng.gen_range(1..length) as usize)
   | |_______________________________________________^ immutable borrow occurs here
...
90 |       if target.soldiers < player.soldiers || target.gold < player.gold {
   |                            --------------- mutable borrow later used here
```

I understand that the compiler is not happy with me borrowing something immutable when I have something borrowed mutably, but if I want to get a random target from the kingdoms vector I need to do this.

What is the correct way to do this? And what programming paradigm rust is trying to enforce here?

Comment: Perhaps use [`split_first_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_first_mut), e.g. `let (player, remainder) = game_state.kingdoms.split_first_mut().unwrap();` then `let target = remainder.get....`

Comment: Simply put, with your existing code Rust isn't smart enough to understand that `player` and `target` don't overlap and therefore that the mutating the former won't affect reads of the latter.  `split_first_mut` guarantees that they don't overlap.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Very weird. Maybe I am doing something non idiomatic way? It feels like this a "patch" to make stuff work but not the intended way to do it.

Comment: Another approach here would be to first select your `target` and copy its `soldiers` and `gold` values into local vars, then borrow `player` and mutate it as desired.

Comment: But I suppose what you're butting up against is whether you really need `player` (which apparently is a "special" kingdom in your game state) to reside in the same collection as all the possible `target`s.  If it does, then borrowing some part of that collection mutably whilst another part is borrowed immutably is always going to be tricky; fortunately slices have the `split_*` methods for precisely that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments explained, use [`split_first_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_first_mut).

```rs
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;

fn try_attack(game_state: &mut GameState) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let (player, rest) = game_state.kingdoms.split_first_mut().unwrap();

    let target = rest.choose(&mut rng).unwrap();

    if target.soldiers < player.soldiers || target.gold < player.gold {
        player.gold += (target.gold as f64 * 0.1) as u32;
        player.soldiers += (target.soldiers as f64 * 0.05) as u32;
    }
}
```

This also uses [`SliceRandom::choose`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.choose).